# How do I auto create student id number in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm very new to MySQL. I created a table for `student`.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    studentId int(10) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    birthday VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7),
    course_name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(studentId )
);
```

I thought it would be nice `studentId` auto create by the system. And I don't know how to do this. This may be a simple question to you guys. Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: `studentId int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows:

*Ex -*

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When inserting data into table you don't have input data to `id`.

```
 INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
        ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
        ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

Which returns -

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | dog     |
|  2 | cat     |
|  3 | penguin |
|  4 | lax     |
|  5 | whale   |
|  6 | ostrich |
+----+---------+
```

*Answer to your question* -

```
CREATE TABLE student(
        studentId int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        firstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        lastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        birthday VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
        gender VARCHAR(7),
        course_name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(studentId )
    );
```

For more information refer [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)